# How can I display 3 buttons on a MessageBox?

Tags: button, xna, messagebox

I would like to show 3 buttons on a MessageBox. I found the Guide.BeginShowMessageBox method, but it isn't working with 3 buttons. Here is my code:

```
Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Info", "This is a test messsage.",
        new List<string> { "OK", "Retry", "Cancel" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
        asyncResult =>
        {
            int? returned = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
            Debug.WriteLine(returned.ToString());
        }, null);
```

Thanks,
Laci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940233.aspx):

> The **maximum number of buttons is *two* on Windows Phone**, and three on Xbox 360 or Windows.

Are you on Windows Phone?

Comment: Then you can't have three buttons.

Comment: I created an animated popup, which is quite similar like the original messagebox. It seems, there isn't another solution for this problem.